# How to configure secondary route in Angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to learn the usage for Angular secondary route and I have a feature module with its own routing module. The html template as follows

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class ="row" style="background-color:beige">
         <H1>Dashboard</H1>
         <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>

    <div class ="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color:skyblue">
            <H1>Foo</H1>
            <router-outlet name="foo"></router-outlet>
           </div> 
          <div class="col-lg-8" style="background-color:darkseagreen">
            <H1>Bar</H1>
            <router-outlet name="bar"></router-outlet>
           </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
```

The dashboard routing module is

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FooComponent } from '../foo/foo.component';
import { BarComponent } from '../bar/bar.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';

const routes: Routes = [ 
    { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
    { path: 'foo',  component: FooComponent, outlet: "foo" },
    { path: 'bar', component: BarComponent, outlet: "bar" }
 ];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
}, )
export class DashboardRoutingModule
```

This is included in the app module - the routing for which is has the root level route.
My expectation is that the /dashboard path should display the primary `DashboardComponent` and display as secondary named outlets the `FooComponent` and `BarComponent`  However the /dashboard route comes up with just the `H1` tags visible

I tried to do reproduce this in plunker but it is not working
`http://plnkr.co/edit/6oSeZDNn6BxIyaDM6uKz?p=preview`

If you know how to get the named secondary outlets to work, please let me know or maybe even get the plunker to work. :-)

Thanks!
Anand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got this work using child route although I would be interested to know if this can be done using with auxiliary/secondary route

```
    const routes: Routes = [ 
    { path: 'dashboard', 
      component: DashboardComponent,
      children : 
      [
          { path: '',  component: FooWidgetComponent, outlet: 'foo'},
          { path: '', component: BarWidgetComponent, outlet: 'bar' }
      ]    
    },
 ];
```

Comment: is this the final routing that you got running? I cannot get it to work properly :(

Answer (score 1):

How about trying this?

```
<a [routerLink]="['', { outlets: { foo: ['foo'] } }]">Contact</a>
```